# Improper checkout of a project - CVS

Tags: cvs, vcs-checkout

I have a project whose structure is as below:

```
ProjectA/: within this directory:

Sub-ProjectA1/  Sub-ProjectA2/
```

`Sub-ProjectA1` was checked out separately in `ProjectA` in an effort to re-use some code. The following command was given:
`cvs checkout -d Sub-ProjectA1 ProjectA1`

Now when I try and `checkout` `ProjectA` separately, `Sub-ProjectA1` does not get checked out. In other words, `cvs checkout ProjectA` leads to the following directory structure:
`ProjectA/:

Sub-ProjectA2/`

The module `Sub-ProjectA1` needs to be checked out separately. How do I ensure that a single checkout command gets me all the sub-directories?

Answer (score 1):

You can define 'modules' on your CVS server. This will generally define a new 'SmartPorejct1' with links to your ProjectA and Sub-ProjectA1. Once you will call "cvs checkout SmartPorejct1" it will checkout all dependent modules.

See http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cvs/cvs_6.html#SEC26 for details.